# Standard way to change image source during runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I am making a very simple Kinect game, but have having a hang-up with WPF. My window just has a very large image. I have several pictures that I want to bind to this image at runtime.

I am sure I could find a way to make it work, but want to make sure I am following the best practices for using image resources in this manner. I am very new to wpf (but alright with C#), so I am sorry if this is a trivial question.

So my question is: what is the best practice when wanting to periodically change the source of a WPF image?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have ViewModel(MVVM pattern) for your window?
I think databinding + trigger maybe is a good choice.

Answer (score -1):

```
        var open = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog { Multiselect = false };
        if (open.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(open.FileName);
            try
            {
                imgBack.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fi.FullName));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                imgBack.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(App.DefaultBackImgPath));
            }

            ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
            brush.ImageSource = imgBack.Source;
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Resources["BackBrush"] = brush;
         }
```